# Date field type - remove "Localised/Fixed"

Tags: custom-fields, date

How do you remove the localised/fixed dropdown on the date fieldtype?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Instead, use the FieldType [DropDate](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dropdate) instead. It's free and very well done.

Comment: DropDate is no longer supported.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick with the EE date fieldtype and not display the localized/fixed select then you could use jQuery. To hide them across the board,

```
$('.hasDatepicker').next('select').hide();
```

will do the trick.

[CP CSS & JS](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) gives a quick way to add JS to the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to hide the elements also works if you are using it in a SAEF form.

```
#cform .choice {display:none;}
```

Answer (score -4):

**Not advised to change core ** but you may comment out the below line at to hide it:

**system/fieldtypes/date/ft.date.php**

LINE 249

> $r .= form_dropdown($date_local, $localized_opts, $localized, 'dir="'.$text_direction.'"');

TO

> // $r .= form_dropdown($date_local, $localized_opts, $localized, 'dir="'.$text_direction.'"');